# Local HTML File - WebBrowser - Windows phone 7

Tags: wpf, silverlight, c#-3.0, webbrowser-control

I need help in displaying HTML File in webbrowser in Windows phone 7 app.

I've an html file in my wpf-silverlight project as resource. Now When the user click on Help button in my App, i need to display this HTML in webbrowser.

> Here is the code, which is giving me an error -

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("AppHelp.html",UriKind.Relative))
```

> But, if i use this code, It's loading fine

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com/AppHelp.html",UriKind.Relative))
```

Please help!

I've change code like this now, but now i'm getting this error:**Invalid URI: A Port is signaled with ':' but could not be parsed.**

```
   Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:AppHelp.html", UriKind.Absolute);
    Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // Navigate to HTML document string
        this.webBrowser1.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method NavigatedToString of WebBrowse object by getting content of html file and put it as parameter of this method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx

samples at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Here is my Code  and I'm getting this eror(Invalid URI: A Port is signaled with ':' but could not be parsed.)  Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:AppHelp.html", UriKind.Absolute);
            Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                // Navigate to HTML document string
                this.webBrowser1.NavigateToString(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

Comment: set build option of your html file as "content" and get stream: Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("yourfilename.html", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: NavigateToString does not play nice with images, though

Comment: Many Thanks ..! faced same problem of URI but that too resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-embed-html-file-in-windows-phone-7/

and for with image in html

you can this, 
[Use local images in Webbrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363174/use-local-images-in-webbrowser-control-wp7/14687376#14687376)

using IsolatedStorages