# How to open file in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a file in my `IsolatedStorage`. I need to open the file from my application. I tried to open it in WebBrowser like this

```
private void OpenFile(string url)
{
    WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
    task.Uri = new Uri(url);
    task.Show();
}
```

but it throws an exception. The error message is Invalid URI: `The format of the URI could not be determined.`

How can I open the file in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See : [Local HTML File - WebBrowser - Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044528/local-html-file-webbrowser-windows-phone-7)
You must use NavigateToString method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have files of type  pdf,doc,xls,ppt,txt or an image. I need to open the one which is selected by user. Just need to open it, in browser or in any other way.