# Relative path to local image in html (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my windows Phone application I have some images with content type. I need show them in my RichTextBox control, so I need to fill relative path. 
For example I have an image in \res.img.jpg
If I try - `<img src='/res/next.png' class='newsimage' width='300' />` - there is no image in result. What is my mistake?

Comment: You need to store the images at isolated storage as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363174/use-local-images-in-webbrowser-control-wp7

Comment: Just to make sure, in your question you said image name is \res.img.jpg and in code it is, /res/next.png. Is it okay??

Comment: @josemiguel.torres , your advise is not work in my case. I save image to isolated storege but it doesn't show an image

Comment: I have Update my question. I am using a RichTextBox control

Comment: Just FYI, the way I use to embed an image inside a RichtextBox is as follow: 

            <RichTextBox Margin="47,208,39,31">
             <Paragraph><Run Text="this is a sample"/></Paragraph>
    <Paragraph> 
           <InlineUIContainer> 
               <Image Source="Image/ApplicationIcon.png" Width="200" Height="100" /> 
           </InlineUIContainer> 
           <Run Text="Hello" /> 
       </Paragraph> 
            </RichTextBox>

Really don't know why you are using <img xx> tag instead of <Image>.