# Load html in windows strore app from appdata folder

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-store-apps

I'm developing windows store app using javascript, html5 and C#. I have developed functionality which downloads zip from web and extracts it to "AppData" folder in "C" drive. That zip file has HTML files. So my question is, I want to display that html in windows app.
 I'm able to load html from web in iframe but not from local drive. I also tried to do it by giving absolute path in iframe but not working.

Comment: Can you try NavigateToString()

Answer (score 1):

Basically, StoreApp's WebView can load the local resource from your app's local storage. "app's local storage" means.. Windows.Storage.Current.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, etc.

If the resources are located outside of your app's local storage, you have 2 options:

1. Copy the all resources to your local storage.
2. Create a 'stream' that have all required resources, then give the stream to webview.

1 is easy.
To refer your html resource, use following syntax.

- ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder - "ms-appdata:///local/hogehoge.html"
- ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder - "ms-appdata:///temp/foobar.html"
- App packages file (like Asset) - "ms-appx-web:///Assets/boee.html"

2 is complicated. Below is an example for 2.

[XAML WebView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Answer (score 0):

Use webbrowser.NavigateToString("parameter"). Your question is a possible duplicate: [Local HTML File - WebBrowser - Windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044528/local-html-file-webbrowser-windows-phone-7)